# mysql join is very slow

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables (MYISAM)

```
create table A (email varchar(50));
create table B( email varchar(50) key 'email' (email));
```

Table A has 130K records
Table B has 20K records

why does this sql statement take very long time (more than two minutes, then i aborted query by Ctrl+C)
Statement is:

```
select count(*) from user A, tmp B where A.email=B.email;
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version? Which engine? Yes, indexing A.email would be better...

Comment: Why are you doing a multitable-select instead of a left join?
I think I'm missing the point here...

Could you do a "describe" on both tables and post the results?
An "explain" on the query would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that the Query optimizer has nothing to go on. Why don't you try defining indexes on the email columns.

Comment: Table A is for another project and i am not allowed to make any change in it :(
however this is what i have in explain
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | index | NULL          | email | 53      | NULL |  21401 |   100.00 | Using index                    | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 136437 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer |

Comment: If you don't add an index on A.email, DB engine will always perform a full table A scan while running this query. There is nothing you can do about it if you are not allowed to add index.

Answer (score 0):

In general, joining on strings is more expensive than joining on shorter data types like int.

You could speed up this query by making sure both email columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If table A has an int ID field then table B should store that ID instead of storing the email string again. That would decrease the DB size and along with indexes would provide a much faster query speed than a string would ever give you.